# Terraform - NAT Exhaustion alerting policy - what's the metric?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, alert

I'm having trouble understanding the 'metrics' used in GCP's alerting policies, and how to use them with terraform.

I'm trying to create an alerting policy, for when we see the NAT Exhaustion errors.

Currently I have this:

```
+ filter          = "metric.type=\"router.googleapis.com/nat/nat_allocation_failed\" resource.type=\"nat_gateway\" metric.label.\"gateway_name\"=\"xx-dmz-region1-nat-gw\" resource.label.\"project_id\"=\"devops-xx-sandbox-xxx\""
```

However, terraform tells me the metric is invalid, and to select a correct metric. How do I find a list of the metrics and choose the right one? I got these details from the query editor, by looking at an existing query in the GCP console

Answer (score 1):

I've just found if I go to the main alert configuration screen (not the alert conditions~) then you can download the json configuration of the alert.

This appears to display the required filter values. The one I had wrong was instead of a metric, it's a resource value for the gateway name.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer and provide proper name of the metric?